# Defragmentation of LVM2 logical volumes

Tags: partition, performance, storage, lvm

Question: Is there a tool supporting de-fragmentation of LVM2 logical volumes? (Making their extents into consistent sequences)

Preferably by defining desired order of extents (something like *"partition A on beginning of disk, B after A, but X on the end of PV"*)

Of course the following cases have to be considered:

- VG consists of one PV
- VG consists of many PV, but each LV sits on one PV
- VG consists of many PV, LVs have their extents across many PV

Whether partitions can be stripped or not, can be discussed.

Know-how:
It's possible to move ranges of extents with `pvmove` , e.g. : `pvmove --alloc anywhere /dev/sdb1:1000-1999 /dev/sdb1:0-999` .

Reason:
Because moving many ranges manually with `pvmove` is purely repeatable thing (questionable if brainless or not), I was curious if there exists tool for automatizing/supporting this process. If not... maybe doing one by myself - do you think such tool would be useful for other people?

Comment: It's possible that there's no tool because there's no use case that requires it. I'm curious, why do you want to defragment? Is there a disk technology where there's a benefit for a typical extent size (4MB)?

Comment: Let's consider traditional HardDrive (not SSD) performance characteristics - beginning of disk offers better performance than end. That's most important factor, why you might like to have extents related to some partition to be placed on beginning.

Comment: For that kind of control, the simple way is to partition the disk into several physical volumes.

Comment: But on the other hand it makes more mess in config files and all setup less flexible. I believe that solutions like mentioned by @JimParis `LVM2 defragmenter` or `pvmove` do the job.

Comment: Doing it with more partitions won't give you more control... you can `pvmove --alloc=anywhere ...` things around inside a pv much easier than moving partitions (like if a LV has to span 2 partitions).

Answer (score 10):

I've used [LVM2 defragmenter](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/source/lvm2defrag.html) before.  It is not the simplest or best written, but it does the trick.

Comment: Looks interesting. I need to try it.

Comment: do you believe this defrag could make it easier to (based on it) implement/create a way to recover a LV partially as stated is possible (was done) here http://serverfault.com/a/665826/163750 ?

Answer (score 1):

Well one more reason for defragmenting would be to reduce chances of data loss when shrinking a logical volume.  A specific reason to shrink a logical volume is to allow expansion of /boot and similar partitions on an older MBR computer hard drive. In my case upgrading from LTS 16.04.03 to LTS 18.04.1 needs more than the 500MB allocated to /boot by the original default installation.

Haven't read the thousands of lines of source code for lvm2 but some of the online help/wiki hint that lvm2 uses pretty brute force truncation when straightforward logical volume shrink procedures are used - as in if files are allocated in the area released by shrinkage you probably will need to restore that list of files (potentially a wild goose chase in itself if application or system packages are involved - or if your user files list is very large).

Comment: If you want to shrink a logical volume, you should first shrink the filesystem stored on said volume. This can be done using commands like `resize2fs` or `btrfs filesystem resize`. After this operation the filesystem is only occupying the first `n` bytes of the volume, where `n` is the size you specified for shrinking the filesystem. Now, truncating/resizing the logical volume to any size larger than `n` bytes is safe. Neither defragmenting the LVM nor the file system will prevent or reduce any data loss! You will have to *resize* the *filesystem*!